# Preview.app only auto-refreshes if you alt-tab to it

Tags: macos, images, preview

I'm working on a program that generates an image.  I can keep the image open in Preview and when the image changes, Preview refreshes it, but only when I alt-tab (sorry, command-tab) to it.  I'd like to keep the image in view and have it auto-refresh without touching it.  Is that possible?

(One ridiculous way I've found to do this is with a script that converts the image to a PDF file which I can keep open in Skim.app (a PDF reader) which has that ability.)

Comment: A program does not have a feature you want it to have, and using another application to solve your problem is a "ridiculous way"?

Comment: The conversion to PDF is what makes it an ugly solution.  If Skim.app could view images (like .png) it would be a great solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open *AppleScript Editor* and enter the following:

```
tell application "Preview" to activate
tell application "AppleScript Editor" to activate
```

Replace the second application's name with the program you want to have frontmost. Save as `scpt` and incorporate a call to this script into your program to refresh Preview:

```
osascript refresh-preview.scpt
```

---

You can alternatively use `Automator` to create a *Service* that receives *no input* with the *Run AppleScript* action and the above code. Save, and assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences*. Not exactly automatic, but easier than getting the mouse to focus Preview.

---

Using the program `open` would be another idea, although using the switch `-g` (don't bring to foreground) opens the file in a new preview window every time its been modified, even if it's already open. All windows get updated though, without being brought to the foreground.

Comment: Oh! This is perfect!  It looks like open -g image.png actually does exactly what I want.  It doesn't seem to open a new preview window each time.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @dreeves Probably depends on the way your program handles changes to the file. I tried it with Automator and the rotate image action, and it behaved as I describe.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) allows you to open images and will also refresh them automatically without any interaction needed.

Comment: Why the downvote? Quoting the asker "If Skim.app [with it's auto refresh feature] could view images (like .png) it would be a great solution". Visual Studio Code is free, unlike XEE which has already been mentioned.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer! I will try it next time I need this. I'm just worried that opening Visual Studio just to view images could be too heavyweight.

Comment: Atom, another code editor, has the same ability with a little less interface showing. (They are very similar.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use XEE, it's an image preview software that includes autorefresh. (http://xee.c3.cx/)

Comment: If this helps anyone: this worked for me for small files, but on large (~17 mb) tiff files, it had a second of static between refreshes. I needed to it for a presentation, so it was almost but not quite the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use applescript to give Preview focus every x seconds.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Activate Preview as done in Daniel Beck's answer.  But with a `delay` command too.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the task simply by appending the following alias to your shell startup scripts (bashrc (or similar))

`alias prefresh='echo "tell application \"Preview\" to activate" | osascript -'`

Then just invoke the alias when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

[Apollo One](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apolloone-photo-viewer-designed/id1044484672?mt=12) (macOS only) seems to do a good job of this, even when running full-screen and not being tabbed to.

It's a basic image viewer. All I had to do was open the correct image and it would reload as the image file changed, even at full screen on a second monitor.

It did crash on me at one point when there was very high CPU usage and I had to reload it. Just something to be aware of.

Also, if you have trouble with it switching to another image in the same folder, the thing to do is just to make sure it's the only image in the folder.

See also the [Apollo One webpage](https://anogeissus.com/products/apollo-one/) (seems to be down at the moment though).

Comment: Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.